# Find sets of columns that present identity in relation

Tags: database-design, identity, relational-algebra

Let's call *identity set* such subset of attributes in relation that are represent identity of a row in this relation and at the same time, when excluding any of the attribute from this identity set, the resulting set of attributes wouldn't be identity set, i.e. in our subject area cannot simultaneously exist two rows that has matching values of all attributes that belongs to specific identity set, but they could exist if they have different value ​​of at least one attribute.

For example, assume relation with attributes A,B,C,D and identity set {A, B}

```
A       B       C       D
--------------------------
1       2       3       4
1       3       2       4
2       2       4       6
1       3       4       6
```

In this relation second and fourth rows have the same values (1,3) in identity set {A,B}, so that they mutually exclusive and this relation not allowed in our subject area.

Is there exist some formalized techniques to finding all 'identity sets' in arbitrary relation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really asking. In the realm of database design, the term "candidate key" seems to cover what you are talking about. In particular (A,B) is not a candidate key, because two rows can have the same value. So if you find all the candidate keys, you will find all the identity sets. You might get more responses if you ask how to find all the candidate keys of a relation (or relational table).

Comment: thanks for your answer, _candidate key_ is exactly what i tried to describe in this question but couldn't find the correct term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my previous comment, the thing to do is to google on "find all candidate keys".

Here is one of the articles found.

http://csc.lsu.edu/~jianhua/fd_slide2_09.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I've found that my *"identity set"* called *candidate key* in fact, thanks to Walter Mitty. Now i can just google my question.

Comment: I wish I had put an answer in, so you could mark it as correct. I googled "finding candidate keys"  and came up with several articles that seem to address your exact concerns.  So I'm glad I provided you with the correct terminology to feed into google.

Comment: I can't mark it within two days after i asked the question. Tomorrow I will do it.